# adding assembly code erase displayed strings

Tags: assembly, operating-system, 16-bit

I try to write my mini OS. I learn from other projects, so I truly have no idea if my code is 'ok' for a bootloader and a kernel. I use assembly 16 bit, NASM, and load the bootloader and the kernel as .bin files to a floppy image. I run the OS with qemu. I came to a point where adding more code lines erase the displayed strings that appear when I start the OS.
For example, if I start the os and it says 'Welcome to my OS!', after adding some code lines it would appear like this 'Welcome to m' (the end disappears).

here is my code:

bootloader.asm

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

                                ; Use the boot drive number passed to us by BIOS in register DL
start:
    xor ax,ax                   ; We want a segment of 0 for DS
    mov ds,ax                   ;     Set AX to appropriate segment value
    mov es,ax                   ; In this case we'll default to ES=DS
    mov bx,0x8000               ; Stack segment can be any usable memory

    mov ss,bx                   ; This places it with the top of the stack @ 0x80000.
    mov sp,ax                   ; Set SP=0 so the bottom of stack will be @ 0x8FFFF


    cld                         ; Set the direction flag to be positive direction

    mov si, welcome_msg
    call print_string

    mov si, kernel_load
    call print_string

    pushf
    stc

    mov ah,00h                  ; Reset Disk Drive
    int 13h

    read_sector:
        mov ax, 0x0
        mov es, ax              ; ES = 0
        mov bx, 0x1000          ; BX = 0x1000. ES:BX=0x0:0x1000 
                                ; ES:BX = starting address to read sector(s) into
        mov ah, 02              ; Int 13h/AH=2 = Read Sectors From Drive
        mov al, 01              ; Sectors to read = 1
        mov ch, 00              ; CH=Cylinder. Second sector of disk
                                ; is at Cylinder 0 not 1
        mov cl, 02              ; Sector to read = 2
        mov dh, 00              ; Head to read = 0
                                ; DL hasn't been destroyed by our bootloader code and still
                                ;     contains boot drive # passed to our bootloader by the BIOS
        int 13h                 ; Read Sectors From Drive

        jc error_kernel_load    ; error loading kernel
        popf
        jmp 0x0:0x1000          ; jmp to kernel offset
        cli                     ; Disable interrupts to circumvent bug on early 8088 CPUs
        hlt                     ; halts the central processing unit (CPU) until the next external interrupt

error_kernel_load:
        mov si, error_msg
        call print_string
        mov si, restart_msg
        call print_string
        mov ah,00               ; wait for key press
        int 16h
        xor ax,ax               
        int 19h                 ; reboot the computer

print_string:                   ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
        lodsb                   ; Get character from string
        or al,al
        jz exit
        mov ah,0x0e
        int 10h                 ; int 10h 'print char' function
        jmp print_string
exit:
        ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Messages to print
    welcome_msg db 'Welcome to Bootloader!!!',0x0D,0x0A,0
    kernel_load db 'Loading kernel....',0x0D,0x0A,0
    error_msg db 'Kernel.bin not found!',0x0D,0x0A,0
    restart_msg db 'Press any key to restart..',0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


times 510-($-$$) db 0       ; Create padding to fill out to 510 bytes
dw      0xaa55              ; Magic number in the trailer of a boot secto
```

kernel.asm

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x1000]

section .data:
    cursor_col:     db     0                ; cursor column
    cursor_row:     db     0                ; cursor row
    line_col:       dw     0                ; line column
    line_row:       dw     0                ; line row

    color:          db     3Fh              ; background and forground color (at start set random the formal way > number+letter)

    mode:           db     0


start:
    mov ax, 07C0h                           ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288                             ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

mov byte [color], 3Fh
    call clear_screen                       ; clear the screen and color it

                                            ; VVV print "Minerald welcome" message VVV
    mov byte [cursor_col], 08               
    mov byte [cursor_row], 28
    call set_cursor                         ; print at the requested position of the screen
    mov si, welcome_string                  ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string                       ; Call our string-printing routine


                                            ; VVV print "Press Space" message VVV
    mov byte [cursor_col], 14
    mov byte [cursor_row], 26
    call set_cursor                         ; print at the requested position of the screen
    mov si, press_key_string                ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string                       ; Call our string-printing routine


    mov ah, 0h                              ; wait for key press
    int 16h                                                 

    mov byte [color], 1Fh
    call clear_screen                       ; clear the screen and color it


    mov byte [cursor_col], 2
    mov byte [cursor_row], 0
    call set_cursor                         ; print at the requested position of the screen
    mov si, basic_background                ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   

    mov byte [cursor_col], 22
    mov byte [cursor_row], 0
    call set_cursor                         ; print at the requested position of the screen
    mov si, basic_background                ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string                       ; Call our string-printing routine


    mov ah, 0                               ; set display mode function.
    mov al, 13h                             ; mode 13h = 320x200 pixels, 256 colors.
    int 10h                                 ; set it!

    ;=================================      ; rectangles
    mov byte [line_col], 80
    mov byte [line_row], 165

    call print_rectangle                    ; print rectangle

    mov byte [line_col], 80
    mov byte [line_row], 135

    call print_rectangle                    ; print rectangle
    ;==================================


end:
    jmp $                                   ; Jump here - infinite loop!
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;
clear_screen:
    mov ah, 06h                             ; Scroll up function
    xor al, al                              ; Clear entire screen
    xor cx, cx                              ; Upper left corner CH=row, CL=column
    mov dx, 184Fh                           ; lower right corner DH=row, DL=column 
    mov bh, byte [color]                    ; set background and foreground color
    int 10h
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;
print_string:                               ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    lodsb                                   ; Get character from string
    or al,al
    jz exit
    mov ah,0x0e                             ; int 10h 'print char' function
    int 10h
    jmp print_string
exit:
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;
set_cursor:
    mov dh, byte [cursor_col]               ; cursor col 
    mov dl, byte [cursor_row]               ; cursor row
    mov ah, 02h                             ; move cursor to the right place
    xor bh, bh                              ; video page 0
    int 10h                                 ; call bios service
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;
print_rectangle:
    %INCLUDE "print_rectangle.asm"
;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Messages to print
    welcome_string       db 'Welcome to  my OS!', 0
    press_key_string     db 'Press any key to continue...', 0
    enter_message_string db 'Enter your message below',0
    APM_ERROR_string     db 'APM Error...'
    basic_background     db '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;END OF KERNEL
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

this are the load commaneds:

```
nasm -f bin -o kernel.bin kernel.asm
nasm -f bin -o bootloader.bin bootloader.asm

dd if=bootloader.bin of=floppy.flp bs=512 seek=0 conv=notrunc 
dd if=kernel.bin of=floppy.flp bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc

qemu-system-i386 -fda floppy.flp
```

edit:

from listing file of nasm before the messages are truncated:

```
   300                                  ; Messages to print
   301 00000191 57656C636F6D652074-         welcome_string       db 'Welcome to my OS!', 0
   302 0000019A 6F204D696E6572616C-
   303 000001A3 644F532100         
   304 000001A8 507265737320616E79-         press_key_string     db 'Press any key to continue...', 0
   305 000001B1 206B657920746F2063-
   306 000001BA 6F6E74696E75652E2E-
   307 000001C3 2E00               
   308 000001C5 456E74657220796F75-         enter_message_string db 'Enter your message below',0
   309 000001CE 72206D657373616765-
   310 000001D7 2062656C6F7700     
   311 000001DE 41504D204572726F72-         APM_ERROR_string     db 'APM Error...'
   312 000001E7 2E2E2E             
   313 000001EA 2D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D-         basic_background     db '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

from listing file of nasm after the messages are truncated:

```
   332                                  ; Messages to print
   333 000001E8 57656C636F6D652074-         welcome_string       db 'Welcome to MineraldOS!', 0
   334 000001F1 6F204D696E6572616C-
   335 000001FA 644F532100         
   336 000001FF 507265737320616E79-         press_key_string     db 'Press any key to continue...', 0
   337 00000208 206B657920746F2063-
   338 00000211 6F6E74696E75652E2E-
   339 0000021A 2E00               
   340 0000021C 456E74657220796F75-         enter_message_string db 'Enter your message below',0
   341 00000225 72206D657373616765-
   342 0000022E 2062656C6F7700     
   343 00000235 41504D204572726F72-         APM_ERROR_string     db 'APM Error...'
   344 0000023E 2E2E2E             
   345 00000241 2D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D-         basic_background     db '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
   346 0000024A 2D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D-
```

Comment: Can you add the lines with messages from listing file of NASM? (`-l kernel.lst` option and copy just the few lines around `welcome_string`) - to see how it gets compiled, and at which offset those are placed.

Comment: @Ped7g I edited the question.

Comment: Is this from the version, which shows the strings already truncated, or is it from version which works? I was sort of afraid you are crossing the 512B sector boundary, but the listing doesn't suggest so, the last 0x1EA offset is still well within 512B, so it's probably something in the code (which I didn't read yet).

Comment: In the code, maybe not related to your bug, but your usage of [`int 10,0E` service](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-e.html) is incorrect, you don't set the `BH` to current page, and it looks to me there may be still some value from sector reading, probably `0x10`, which makes it probably work by accident, but I'm reluctant to dig deep into code which is written carelessly, and probably "verified" just by executing it and checking output. Stop doing that, run it in debugger single stepping over each instruction, and validate all assumptions/effects of instructions, don't rely on output.

Comment: Actually one another major thing... check listing of kernel.lst at the beginning, I don't believe `section` directive is relevant, as you use `bin` format for output, so your kernel very likely starts at `0000:1000` with data bytes, not instructions, which is probably another sheer luck, that you get even somewhat meaningful output after executing the data. Mixing `section` vs `org` doesn't make sense, either you are using `section` and more complex executable format, where linker will sort out memory layout according to linker script provided, or you use binary where you need to layout self.

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for your comments. I'm new to this and I'm still learning. I edited the post with the listing file after adding lines of code, the previous was before the messages were truncated.  If I really cross the 512B, what should I do? load another sector? 
and one more thing, I am new to linux as well, and I couldn't figure out how I debug assembly with gdb, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: And I didn't quite understand the part of the 'section' and 'org'. Could you explain please what is a section exactly and what should I do? Just erase the section .data label?

Comment: If you cross 512B sector boundary, then yes, you have to load more than 1 sector then (you have to load (size_of_kernel/512) rounded up number of sectors). You run your boot loader code inside the QEMU virtual machine, so you need debugger which is capable to debug VM code, it's not as trivial as debugging normal app code running under your host OS (and that is neither trivial), so that's why I frown when I see people who are new to assembly to pick up on bootloader and kernel programming instead of learning assembly basics first, because that's like tripling the size of problems at start.

Comment: And I'm not into OS dev, so I don't know how to debug code running inside QEMU, from other OS dev questions here it looks like running bootloaders with BOCHS simulator is a bit more debugging-friendly, although I myself was unable to set it up in 5 minutes I allocated for a try. ... about section ... take it from the other point of view, you load byte data "machine code" from disk into memory, then execute it (without any post-processing of the loaded data), so all the instructions and addresses are already defined in the binary data. `org` directive adjusts internal offsets during assembly.

Comment: With other executable formats like `ELF` (32 or 64 bit), the assembling process will produce first object files, which have only relative local offsets within the object file, not final addresses, the `org` is not used at all. Object files are then collected by linker, and final executable is assembled from then, connecting various symbols between different object files, and also putting data and code into [separate sometimes] areas, where they belong according to linker script used for linking, each data or code part has defined target section by `section` directive, which is for linker.

Comment: As you are producing binary file, what you see in listing: `line_number address(offset) machine_code_bytes` is literally what you have in the .bin file (well, only the machine code part, the line numbers and offsets are just information for you, from where the machine code was compiled, and to where it will land) ... you our `kernel.bin` starts with few zeroes created by `db 0`, and you will in bootloader `jmp 0:0x1000` at those data bytes and execute them as instructions. (because for CPU the memory byte is memory byte, it can't tell what is code and what are data, there's no difference).

Comment: And in 16b real mode the machine code `00 00` is opcode of instruction `add [bx+si],al` ... etc.. so that's what you execute. ("db" is not instruction, it's directive to emit byte values by assembler, so when you want some byte in machine code with value `13`, you don't need to recall which instruction has opcode starting with `13`, but you can write `db 13`... and vice versa, the instruction mnemonics are there to help you to not have to recall that `ret` is `db 195` (while it would work, for most people it would be too much to remember all instructions encodings and write them as numbers).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm still in high school and I coded in assembly before [on windows], but I'm still not 100% with all the basics apparently. The last comment with the fact that your can use 'db 195' instead of 'ret' is new to me and quite interesting. It really helped, thank you a lot :)

Comment: Hmm, read something about principles/architecture of computers, and what is "machine code" and how assembly instructions are encoded... and take another look on the listing file and compare it viewing content of `kernel.bin` (in linux install "hd" = hexdump? On Ubuntu you can find it in package "bsdmainutils") to see how that machine code in listing is the only content which ends in the "bin" file, and that's what the CPU does see+execute (but in "binary" as CPU operates only with the bits - i.e. electricity current levels in cells, which are treated as logical values 0 or 1).

Comment: It may feel everything a bit complex and weird, but try to think about it more from the HW designer point of view, how you are working with 0/1 electricity currents all the time, and how everything is designed to be actually dumb-simple, i.e. the memory content doesn't have any flags if it stores instruction, integer or float, that would be too much fuss to deal in the transistors, etc.. after you will enter this machine-like point of view, you will figure out soon the whole machine and assembly is actually very simple overgrown deterministic calculator, changing its state every clock tick.

Comment: Then lot of that "assembly weird" will make lot more sense, as assembly is not as much a programming language (logical, human oriented) as high level languages, as it is more mirror of the HW design of the CPU, so it's logical from the point of view of putting millions of transistors onto small chip, the "programming logic" is secondary in the process, allowing for application being created with the CPU, but not bothering if some particular instruction behaves "quirky" from human logic point of view, if the HW design that way is more elegant and performant.

Comment: All of what you said make a lot of sense, I'll read more about the architecture :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your original question:

That's because your kernel gets longer, and it is more than one disk sector size in total, but you keep loading only one sector (512 bytes) of it into memory, so the rest of the string stays on the disk only, never entering the memory.

There're also several other problems (**some** mentioned in my comments), but those are not really relevant to the string truncation, and I'm not in mood+time to review all of your bootloader+kernel and fix all of the bugs you have there, so I will stop here (answer-wise).